# Make a custom SwipeRefreshLayout Indicator?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

How would I go about making a custom indicator that would use a drawable object with a custom animation for the `SwipeRefreshLayout`?

I looked over the source code for `SwipeRefreshLayout` and I noticed the `CircleImageView` object was private.

Is there anyway to modify the `ImageView`?

Answer (score 29):

You can change the drawable via reflection, not sure how good this idea is. Something like :

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_swiperefresh_id);
try {
    Field f = mSwipeRefreshLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCircleView");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)f.get(mSwipeRefreshLayout);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable_file);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Wonder how this effects the MaterialProgressDrawable object

Comment: this would only change the drawable

Comment: I would like to put a custom drawable, but I'm concerned about the CircleImageView. See link: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/CircleImageView.java testing it out now

Comment: I checked using simple drawable, but not with custom drawable

Comment: Is there any way to add animations to this drawable? Like change its color? If there is a workaround for that it would satisfy this answer.

Comment: Write your own MaterialProgressDrawable (like
MaterialProgressDrawable extends Drawable implements Animatable)
and set it using img.setImageDrawable(materialProgressDrawable).
Its gonna work

Comment: okay! Im going to test this out really quick if it works, you're awesome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93620/discussion-between-abhishesh-and-andyroid).

Comment: Will Android's SecurityManager prevent me from using this in Production?

Comment: @BMM which loader you want to hide?? If you dont want to use swipe to refresh, you can silently update without notifying user

Comment: I used this snippet but my loader is not visible now. only the background circle is shown. Any idea how to show that?

Answer (score 3):

Try https://github.com/liaohuqiu/android-Ultra-Pull-To-Refresh.
Modify System widget is  troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use reflection like in example above you could get child from your SwipeRefreshLayout with 0 index. It will CircleImageView so you could set any Drawable to it.

Answer (score 0):

**This might be very late to answer but here is the solution to customize and also play the animation:-**

```
final private LottieDrawable ld = new LottieDrawable();
Field f = swipeRefreshLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCircleView");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ImageView imgVW = (ImageView)f.get(swipeRefreshLayout);
            ld.setBounds(0, 0, 64, 64);
            @SuppressLint("WrongThread") LottieResult<LottieComposition> result = LottieCompositionFactory.fromAssetSync(App.activity, "LottieSpinner.json");
            ld.setComposition(result.getValue());
            ld.setRepeatCount(LottieDrawable.INFINITE);
            imgVW.setImageDrawable(ld);
```

**Inside your SwipeRefreshLayout listener:-**

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
ld.playAnimation();
})
```

**Once network call is finished:-**

```
void stop() {
    ld.stop()
}
```